# Unexpected templating type error occurred: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Tags: ansible

This is my playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        userdata: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% for i in userdata %}
          {% set keys=i.keys()|map('trim') %}
          {% set values=i.values()|map('trim') %}
          - {{ dict(keys|zip(values)) }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfilter %}
```

Error message when trying to run the task:

```
{"msg": "Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% filter from_yaml %}\n{% for i in userdata %}\n{% set keys=i.keys()|map('trim') %}\n{% set vals=i.values()|map('trim') %}\n- {{ dict(keys|zip(vals)) }}\n{% endfor %}\n{% endfilter %}\n): sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found"}
```

It says it found a list instead of str. How do I resolve this error?

The userdata variable is a list of key-value dictionaries. I intend to create a CSV data using userdata variable later:

```
{
  "userdata": [
    {
      "ClassType": "Part Time",
      "Code": " #3091 ",
      "DateofSubmission": " 14/5/2023 ",
      "Description": "NIL",
      "FirstName": " Peter ",
      "LastName": " Miller ",
      "path": "OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
    },
    {
      "ClassType": "Full Time",
      "Code": " #3092 ",
      "DateofSubmission": " 2/5/2023 ",
      "Description": "NIL",
      "FirstName": " Sam ",
      "LastName": " Keller ",
      "path": "OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
    },
    {
      "ClassType": "Flexi",
      "Code": " #3093 ",
      "DateofSubmission": " 10/5/2023 ",
      "Description": "NIL",
      "FirstName": " Judy ",
      "LastName": " Higgins ",
      "path": "OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I remove {% filter from_yaml %}, the userdata becomes this:

```
"userdata": "- {'FirstName': 'Rakesh Kumar', 'LastName': 'Pandey', 'AliasName': '', 'EffectiveJoiningDate': '31/5/2023', 'EmploymentType': 'Full Time', 'Designation': 'Account Manager', 'Department': 'Sales', 'SectionCode': '', 'ReportingManager': 'Farzeen Np', 'DateofSubmission': '14/5/2023', 'PhysicalLastDay': '', 'LastWorkingDate': '', 'Description': '#3091', 'Office': 'CTCSG', 'SamAccountName': 'rakesh.p'}\n- {'FirstName': 'Muhammad Jaafar', 'LastName': 'Shahul Hameed', 'AliasName': '', 'EffectiveJoiningDate': '19/5/2023', 'EmploymentType': 'Contract', 'Designation': 'HR', 'Department': 'HR', 'SectionCode': '', 'ReportingManager': 'Steven Tan', 'DateofSubmission': '2/5/2023', 'PhysicalLastDay': '', 'LastWorkingDate': '', 'Description': '#3092', 'Office': '<not set>', 'SamAccountName': 'muhammadjaafar.sh'}\n- {'FirstName': 'Abby', 'LastName': 'Tan Wan Ling', 'AliasName': '', 'EffectiveJoiningDate': '25/5/2023', 'EmploymentType': 'Sub Contract', 'Designation': 'Middleware Engineer', 'Department': 'Service Delivery', 'SectionCode': 'Implementation and Break-Fix-SD01', 'ReportingManager': 'Jose Ashwin', 'DateofSubmission': '10/5/2023', 'PhysicalLastDay': '', 'LastWorkingDate': '', 'Description': '#3093', 'Office': 'NEA', 'SamAccountName': 'abby.t'}\n"
}
```

Comment: If you drop the `{% filter from_yaml %}`, what does the generated data look like? It sounds like you're creating something that isn't valid YAML syntax. What does `userdata` look like? Without that information we can't reproduce this behavior.

Comment: I have already updated my post. All I want to do with that task is to remove any spacing between the " " in the values. For example, removing the spaces in " #3091 " to become "#3091". Maybe there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're using the string representation of `dict(keys|zip(values)`, which looks something like:

```
{
  'ClassType': 'Part Time',
  'Code': '#3091',
  'DateofSubmission': '14/5/2023',
  'Description': 'NIL',
  'FirstName': 'Peter',
  'LastName': 'Miller',
  'path': 'OU=fulltime,
  OU=Test OU,
  DC=localdemo,
  DC=local'
}
```

That's not valid JSON (and also not valid YAML), so rather than creating a YAML dictionary you just get a big string.

The simplest fix is probably to use the `to_json` filter. Assuming that `data.json` contains your sample data, like this:

```
{
  "userdata": [
    {
      "ClassType": "Part Time",
      "Code": " #3091 ",
      "DateofSubmission": " 14/5/2023 ",
      "Description": "NIL",
      "FirstName": " Peter ",
      "LastName": " Miller ",
      "path": "OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
    },
    {
      "ClassType": "Full Time",
      "Code": " #3092 ",
      "DateofSubmission": " 2/5/2023 ",
      "Description": "NIL",
      "FirstName": " Sam ",
      "LastName": " Keller ",
      "path": "OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
    },
    {
      "ClassType": "Flexi",
      "Code": " #3093 ",
      "DateofSubmission": " 10/5/2023 ",
      "Description": "NIL",
      "FirstName": " Judy ",
      "LastName": " Higgins ",
      "path": "OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
    }
  ]
}
```

The following playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    - data.json
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        userdata: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {% for i in userdata %}
          {% set keys=i.keys()|map('trim') %}
          {% set values=i.values()|map('trim') %}
          - {{ dict(keys|zip(values))|to_json }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfilter %}

    - debug:
        var: userdata
```

Produces this output:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "userdata": [
        {
            "ClassType": "Part Time",
            "Code": "#3091",
            "DateofSubmission": "14/5/2023",
            "Description": "NIL",
            "FirstName": "Peter",
            "LastName": "Miller",
            "path": "OU=fulltime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
        },
        {
            "ClassType": "Full Time",
            "Code": "#3092",
            "DateofSubmission": "2/5/2023",
            "Description": "NIL",
            "FirstName": "Sam",
            "LastName": "Keller",
            "path": "OU=parttime,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
        },
        {
            "ClassType": "Flexi",
            "Code": "#3093",
            "DateofSubmission": "10/5/2023",
            "Description": "NIL",
            "FirstName": "Judy",
            "LastName": "Higgins",
            "path": "OU=flexi,OU=Test OU,DC=localdemo,DC=local"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I added the to_json filter, however, I still get the exact same error message

Comment: The playbook presented in this answer runs without errors using `ansible-playbook` version `2.14.1` (and the sample data included in the answer). I'm curious what behavior you get if you use the sample data and playbook presented in this answer; give that a shot and let me know.

Comment: I should add that my original task and your suggestion runs without any issue on ansible CLI, but when I run the same playbook on ansible controller, it gives the error message stated above.

Comment: What is the difference in your own words between "Ansible cli" and "Ansible controller"? For most people watching the Ansible tag, the controller is the machine/VM/container/... where you run the Ansible playbook from the cli or anything else.

Comment: 'Ansible CLI' is the terminal where I type 'ansible-playbook play.yml' to run the playbook, and I am also able to edit the playbook's role directory files in the same terminal.
'Ansible controller', is Ansible Automation Platform Automation Controller. In automation controller, I click on 'launch' job template and it will run the same playbook that I have in the terminal. In this automation controller, somehow is it finding issues with the playbook (the set_fact task layout, I suppose), saying that it expected str instance, but got a list instead.

Comment: So I suggest you use the term "Ansible Automation Platform" for clarity, because as described above, your cli as much as your redhat gui product are both ansible controllers (aka control nodes) when they run your playbook. And regarding your direct problem, you should check the version of ansible in your local machine and inside your platform as the different result might come from there.